# How to use Azure CLI function in function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm using a Azure CLI to upload some files to a storage blob:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch 
  --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
  --destination "$web" 
  --account-key <generated_key>
  --account-name $(prSourceBranchName)
```

For this I need the `--acount-key` from the container. I can render the key through:

```
call az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n $(prSourceBranchName) --query [0].value -o tsv
```

This outputs the correct key.

How do I get the data from the `az storage account keys list` function in my `--account-key` value?

I've tried directly referencing the function in the other function:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key call az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n $(prSourceBranchName) --query [0].value -o tsv 
    --account-name $(prSourceBranchName)

call az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n $(prSourceBranchName) --query [0].value -o tsv 
    --account-name $(prSourceBranchName)

call az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key (az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n $(prSourceBranchName) --query [0].value -o tsv)
    --account-name $(prSourceBranchName)
```

This outputs:

```
call az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "d:\a\r1\a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key call az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n *****to --query [0].value -o tsv 
    --account-name *****to

ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n *****to

call az storage blob upload-batch 
    --source "d:\a\r1\a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" 
    --destination "$web" 
    --account-key az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n *****to --query [0].value -o tsv 
    --account-name *****to

ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n *****to

call az storage blob upload-batch --source "d:\a\r1\a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build" --destination "$web" --account-key (az storage account keys list -g CustomersV2 -n *****to --query [0].value -o tsv) --account-name *****to

--account-name was unexpected at this time.
```

It looks the `az storage account keys list -g` function is rendered as a string, not as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `@` to call a function like the blow I test:

```
az storage blob list --container-name $containername --account-name $accountname --account-key @(az storage account keys list -g $groupname -n $accountname--query [0].value -o tsv)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Yes using @(function) does work, but in the end I end stopped using azure CLI and used AzureRM in a Azure powershell.